# How come this page came up during my Google search

Tags: google-search

I did a Google search of "[perl equivalent of python str function](http://www.google.co.za/search?hl=en&pwst=1&&sa=X&ei=WohvTYLeHYS04gb0j9XHDQ&ved=0CBUQvwUoAQ&q=perl+equivalent+of+python+str+function&spell=1)", but looking in [that page](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) (first hit), there is no mention of Perl. I checked the source too, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, thinking that maybe it was hidden somewhere, but no luck.

Comment: looking in _which_ page?

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the [current google cache for that page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aRDjl6J1HakUJ%3awiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips+perl+equivalent+of+python+str+function&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=za&source=www.google.co.za), you'll see that it *does* contain the word 'perl'. Multiple times even. So that means that this page must have been changed recently, and the google bot hasn't passed by again. Wait a couple of days, and that result wont show up any more for that search query!

Comment: You are looking at the wrong page. BTW the current version of your page does contain the word.

Comment: @Tshepang: Well, apparently it's solved already :) I don't see a link to http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html nowhere in the results - at least not the first page - for "perl equivalent of python str function".

Comment: This is strange. It appears first when I use Chrome, but doesn't appear on first page when I use Epiphany. Maybe Chrome or Google are being too clever?

Comment: @Tshepang: maybe you're logged in to your google account on one of the browsers, and not on the other one, as google uses your search history also, when returning search results (when you're logged in).

Comment: You are right, I just checked. Damn, that makes things so distorted. Bad Google.